# I keep getting the following error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "blog_post" already exists in my django app

Tags: python, django-models, traceback

When I try to Migrate I get the following error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "blog_post" already exists
```

now I have assumed that the message means that I am trying to make a column named "name" and one with the same name already exists. So I looked at my model to make sure one didn't exist and it doesn't. I don't understand what the issue is. Here is my model. Oh and I ran migrations first before I ran migrate. so that's not the issue

```
class Post(models.Model):

STATUS_CHOICES = (
   ('draft', 'Draft'),
   ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                        unique_for_date='publish')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                          null=True,
                          blank=True,
                          height_field='height_field',
                          width_field='width_field')
image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500,
                             null=True,
                             blank=True,
                             )
height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                   null=True,
                                   blank=True,
                                   )
width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,
                                  )
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           related_name='blog_posts',
                           null=True,
                           blank=True,)
body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,)
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default='draft')
video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,)
url = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                       null=True,
                       blank=True, )
name = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                        null=True,
                        blank=True, )

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
```

and here is my views.py

```
    def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
    object_list = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')
else:
    object_list = Post.published.all().order_by('-id')
articles = Article.objects.all()[:8]
# latest_article = Post.published.latest('created')

query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    object_list = object_list.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query) |
        Q(body__icontains=query) |
        Q(tags__name__in=[query])
    ).distinct()

tag = None
if tag_slug:
    tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
    object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 15) # 3 posts in each page
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

css_left = 'col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-centered'
# css_right = 'col-xs-12 col-lg-3'
template = 'blog/post/list.html'
title = 'home'
page_num = paginator.num_pages
local = os.getenv('_system_name')
context = {
    'page': page,
    'posts': posts,
    'tag': tag,
    'title': title,
    'articles': articles,
    'css_left': css_left,
    'paginator': paginator,
    'page_num': page_num,
    'local': local,
    'query': query
    # 'css_right': css_right
    # 'latest': latest_article
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

and here is the traceback

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying blog.0008_auto_20160625_1708...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "blog_post" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 396, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "blog_post" already exists
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar problem. This worked for me

```
./manage.py migrate --fake
```

and then:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
```

just to make sure and then ran

```
./manage.py migrate
```